# JQuery functions declaration and reusing it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following jQuery code

```
$('#rta_ad_yes').click(function(){
    $('#rta_ad_pref, #rta_ad_psn').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#div_ad_pref, #div_ad_psn').addClass('has-warning');
});

$('#rta_fp_yes').click(function(){
    $('#rta_ad_fpref, #rta_ad_fpsn').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#div_ad_fpref, #div_ad_fpsn').addClass('has-warning');
});
```

If you look at the above code it seems i'm doing same coding to achieve the same result.. `$('#rta_ad_yes')` and `$('#rta_fp_yes')` in two different pages

sorry to not mentioning my question question how can i declare and call that function provide parameters rather than typing the whole thing again and again.. i dont know how to declare function and reuse it in jquery not very good at jquery

Comment: So what is the question? Put the code in a `.js` file so you can re-use it.

Comment: It *seems* so, but that's not actually the case (the selectors you use are different, e.g. `#rta_ad_pref` versus `#rta_ad_fpref`). You can still mutualize this through a function that takes three selectors (oh, and a boolean too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the following code.

```
function isEmpty (test_obj, element){
    if(!test_obj.val().length > 0){
        element.addClass('has-warning');
        return false;
    }else{
        element.removeClass('has-warning');
        return true;
    }
};
```

and reuse that like below

```
var x = isEmpty($('#rta_cl_fn'), $('#div_cl_fn'));
```

hope that helped

Answer (score 1):

Try

[.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

```
$('#rta_ad_yes', '#rta_fp_yes').click(function () {
    var id = (this.id.split('_')[1] == 'fp')? 'f' : '';//get ad or fp from id
    //if it's `fp` than add `f` if not than empty string .
    $('#rta_ad_' + id + 'pref, #rta_ad_' + id + 'psn').prop('disabled', function(){
         return id.length;//return false if 0 and for 1 return true .
    }); //make id out of it
    $('#div_ad_' + id + 'pref, #div_ad_' + id + 'psn').addClass('has-warning');
});
```

Comment: This still does not handle the different booleans passed to `prop()`.

Comment: is this reusable i mean i've 100's of those textboxes not on one page though. i just want to know if i could have that code so i could reuse it

Comment: @UsmanSharifAmjadKhan it depends on what your html is and what is id structure .

Comment: ad = accident details
fp = first party

Comment: @TusharGupta dont know what you mean by html and structure but it is a simple question about declaring a function like declaring functions in java php c# c++ with some parameters and reusing it with providing different parameter values.. is that simple enough

Comment: i'm typing same thing again and again in the above mentioned case(in my question) and please dont worry about boolean value being false or ture i can make two different functions... one with true value and one with false value... and my id patteren is same throughout the website

Comment: @UsmanSharifAmjadKhan yes it will work and it will handle bool value also .you can test it .

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to abstract that in a function?

```
var disableAndWarn = function (config) {
  $("#" + config.id1 + ', ' + "#" + config.id2).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  $("#" + config.id3 + ', ' + "#" + config.id4).addClass('has-warning');
}
```

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lav911/MZrtr/1/)

**Edit**: Changed your `.prop('disabled', true)` into `.attr('disabled', 'disabled')` since I believe that's what you intended.